# Rounds needed in elimination tournament

Tags: algorithm

I was just wondering if anyone has a formula to evaluate the number of round in a competition in single elimination based on :
- the number of teams involved (can be >2)
- the number of qualified teams for the next round.

This is easy for 1v1 or 1v1v1v1 with 2 teams qualified per match each rounds but I am stuck for 1v1v1 with 1 or 2 qualified teams...

Thanks !

As requested, Examples :

let's start with 32 players who plays COD on 4 at a time on a "free for all" mode (each player is alone against the others).

```
1st round : 32 players distributed in 8 matches of 4 players
```

Here we want to know how many rounds it will take to go to a final match with 4 players if we choose to keep the 1 or 2 or even 3 bests players in each matches.

1st case : if we keep the 2 best of each matchs :

```
2nd round : 16 players distributed in 4 matches of 4 players
```

2nd case : if we keep only the first

```
2nd round : 8 players distributed in 2 matches of 4 players
```

(In the second case we can foresee a problem because at the next turn we will have only 2 players left which is not enough to fill a game)

The idea is to find a mathematical formula that give me the necessary number of round with the following variables :

```
 * NumberOfPlayers                 : the quantity of initial participants
 * NumberOfPlayersInAGame          : the quantity of participants in a game
 * NumberOfPlayersQualifiedInAGame : the quantity of participants qualified for the next round in after a game
```

Enjoy :D

Comment: What does "1v1v1" mean? What makes a team qualified?

Comment: If 2 players are left over in a round, do they play 1vs1? If 1 player is left over do you build 2 groups with 2 players that play 1v1? Or how is this handled? And if 2 teams are qualified 1v1v1 this would mean there are 2 winners?

Comment: @Adam it means "free for all", each player compete against the N-1 others. at the end of a game, a ranking is computed and the qualified are either the first, ther first and second , it could be the third if we are in 1v1v1v1

Comment: @maraca no. You still play the same format all along the competition. For instance, in the case of three 1v1v1 with only obne qualified , the Thre winners will compete together in a new 1v1v1 round. If there are 2 qualified per match, we could then have 2 new match with the qualified players.

Comment: btw i do not search for an algorithm, I could do it easly. The idea is to find a mathematical formula that give me the necessary number of round with the following variables : nulberOfPlayers, NumberOfPlayersInAGame, NumberOfPlayersQualifiedInAGame.

Comment: You have to define the problem much better. So far it looks to me like the number of rounds is 1: put everyone into a free-for-all 1v1v1v1v1v...v1.

Comment: @Adam there are limits in the number of 1V1V1V1... Btw, the context is video games.

Comment: The reason you're having trouble with the answer is because you haven't managed to write down the whole question yet. Start over, but this time write down *all* the rules, who advances and who is eliminated each round, how many winners there can be at the end, etc. An example bracket can also help.

Comment: @Adam modified my question :D

Comment: @Mouais  yes my question was something else, simply put, what happens 1v1v1 if there are 5 players? With 1 winner the answer is easy for 3, 9, 27, 81, ... players for other amounts it's more difficult. And for 2 winners 1v1v1 the only nice amounts are 2 and 3 players :-)

Comment: @maraca let's suppose we have the expected number of players (3, 9 , 27 and so on for 1v1v1 and with only the first auqlified or 4, 16, 64  ... for 1v1v1v1 with 2 bests qualified )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `1` winner in a `k`-tournament (e.g. `k = 3` means 1v1v1) and `N` players, where `N` element `k^x` and `x` is a positive integer it takes `g` games (java code):

```
public int countGames(int players, int k) {
    if (players <= 1) {
       return 0;
    } else {
       players = players / k;
       // the number of remaining players per round is the same as the number of games
       return players + countGames(players, k);
    }
}
```

Or mathematically:

```
g = sum(i from 1 to logk(N), k^(i-1))                           ( logK(N) = ln(N) / ln(k)  )
```

Comment: Nice one @maraca . I can add the 'w' variable which is the number of winner : players = w * players / k ; :)

Comment: @Mouais yes true, but the number of games per round is still players / k and if (players < k) return 0; (if this solved your problem please accept the answer by clicking the checkmark on top left of the answer)

Comment: @Mouais You can also define logk for integers like `int logK(int k, int n) {if (n < k) return 0; else return 1 + logK(k, n/k);}`. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: Or  better: `int ret = 0; while (n >= k) {n /= k; ret++;} return ret;`

Answer (score 1):

In a *single elimination* tournament each match eliminates one entrant , by definition. Therefore if there are N entrants and the tournament completes by producing M winners there must, by definition of a *single elimination* tournament, have been N-M matches completed. It is usually the case that M is identically 1, and therefore N-1 matches must have taken place.

Similarly each round can be analyzed, and if a match is composed of two entrants playing to determine a single winner, then a round with 2*N entrants and N survivors must have had 2*N - N = N matches. If there were 2*N + 1 entrants to the round, with one entrant having a bye, then there are N+1 survivors of the round and again 2*N+1 - (N+1) = N matches must have been played.

By working backward from the required single winner, noting the constraint that for each round each entrant plays only one game, thus eliminating only one contestant, then the maximum number of entrants supported by a *single elimination* tournament of K rounds is 2^k.

Comment: well for 1v1v1v1 come tournaments qualified the 2 bests to simplify the managment of the tree (it becomes then mostly like a 1v1). On what you said we can deduce in the case that there are only one qualified and P players in a game that for N entrants we have P^k = N so k = log(n)/log(p) . Correct ? But what about if we qualified more than the first ?

Comment: @Mouais: Please come again - I don't understand a word of that comment.

Comment: the number of entrant for a single match could be more than 2 and then the number of qualified could be more than 1. Does it clarify my comment ?